# how to preserve properties value in the fragment after switching tab in bottom navigation view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have 4 tabs in the bottom navigation view called :

1. Home
2. Search
3. Favourite
4. Profile

here is the simplified code of my profile fragment

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    private var lastDocumentFromQuery : DocumentSnapshot? = null
    private var attendedEvents = ArrayList<Event>()
    private var currentPage = 0
    private var isLoadingData = false
    private var isInTheLastPage = false
    private var noMoreDataAvailable = false

    lateinit var linearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager
    lateinit var model : ProfileViewModel

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        mContext = context
        activity?.let { mActivity = it }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        return fragmentView
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)


    }

}
```

if I am in the Profile tab, and the switch to tab Favourite for example, the value of properties in my `ProfileFragment` class will be gone and it seems it is recreated from the beginning again.

I mean these properties:

```
    private var lastDocumentFromQuery : DocumentSnapshot? = null
    private var attendedEvents = ArrayList<Event>()
    private var currentPage = 0
    private var isLoadingData = false
    private var isInTheLastPage = false
    private var noMoreDataAvailable = false
```

those properties will change when user interacts in ProfileFragment. and I want to preserve the values of all those properties, not back to the default value after switching the tab.

I have tried to use view model to preserve the values, but  the method `onCleared()` on my viewModel class is triggered when I switch the tab from tab Profile to Favourite for example, so that the preserved properties will also be gone.

I am using navigation controller component, and in my MainActivity I set this appBarConfiguration 
(I don't know whether the code below will give effect to my problem or not)

```
// set up top hierarchy destination

val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
   R.id.destination_home,
   R.id.destination_search,
   R.id.destination_favourite,
   R.id.destination_profile)
)

setSupportActionBar(toolbar)         
searchToolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
```

so how to preserve the values of those properties ? sorry I am new in Android development

Comment: First thing make sure that you are not destroying fragment and second thing you can use shared preference for lifetime data storage of parcable for temporary data holder.

Comment: `onActivityCreated`? Why not `onViewCreated`? Also, to support the scenario you are looking for, you just need to add https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/1f4840cfb8b1c1820d375ee208a18bd743ab5326/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt#L35-L250 according to the navigation aac samples